# opencv in Ubuntu does not show image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to openCV, have recently obtained a version of openCV 2.4.8 and was successfully able to integrate it with Code blocks.

Apparently library seems to work fine, but when I'm trying to display image using imshow it displays the window but doesn't display image in it.

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   
    if(! image.data )                              
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   

    waitKey(0);                                       
    return 0;
}
```

[output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y955j.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the properties of the image, such as the number of rows and columns, to see if they match with the actual image? You normally don't need the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR option, so you might  also want to remove that and check the result.

Comment: After removing CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR option, still, it gives same output.Thanks

Comment: Getting the same error on OSX with OpenCV 3.2. @qazwsx have you managed to get past this issue ?